# Android Webview getting ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE with Paypal

Tags: android, paypal, webview

I'm using a Webview that redirects to a Paypal transaction. The problem is that in Android devices before 4.4, the URL

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=sometokenprovided

gets me an ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE error. I read some possible solutions, but none worked. Some say that this error only occours with the sandbox, not in production, but I want to be prepared if they change the production server too.

So I'm asking if there is a known working way to fix this issue.

Also, have in account I'm not getting this method called:

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
```

but instead this one is the one called:

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
```

Can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance,
João

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your HTTP requests are happening over TLS 1.2 instead of SSLv3.  It's a server software stack issue.

Comment: But it seems that TLS 1.2 only works on KitKat+ devices. I need to add support for pre-KitKat ones.

Comment: PayPal (and almost all web service providers) are no longer accepting requests over SSLv3.  They now require TLS 1.2 for security purposes.  That's all I can tell you.